# How to add a listener into init function - EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, listener

I'm trying to make a quick search with a plugin, in my **Extjs** (4.2.5) application but, i don't wanna add the listener into the combo, i wanna make a plugin for having more cleaned my code, but I really don't have a real idea about how to add my listener into the `init()` function.

```
Ext.define("custom.FilterCustom", {
    extend: "Ext.AbstractPlugin",
    xtype: 'pluginCustom',
    fieldName: '',
    constructor: function() {
        var me = this;
    },
    init: function() {
        var me = this;
        // Here is  where i'm trying to add the listener, but nothing happens.
    }

});
```

and by the way, i don't know if i'm forgetting some lines of code, it's my first time doing a **plugin**.

Here's the `combobox`:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    padding: 5,
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: words,
    queryMode: 'local',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    plugins: [Ext.create('M5.view.custom.FilterCustom', {
        fieldName: 'name'
    })]
});
```

If anyone can help me with this, i'm gonna be very glad! .x

Comment: See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.AbstractPlugin-method-init

Comment: oh god, thanks! @EvanTrimboli(?)